# What strategies can I use to evaluate a limit when Limit[] returns unevaluated

Tags: numerics, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to find the following limit using *Mathematica*:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{k-1}{N}\right)^N$$

The problem is taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189087) and is known to converge to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{e-1}$. However, using `Limit` in a straightforward manner returns unevaluated:

```
Limit[Sum[((k - 1)/n)^n, {k, 1, n}], n -> ∞]
(* Limit[Sum[((k - 1)/n)^n, {k, 1, n}], n -> ∞] *)
```

How can I explore this problem using *Mathematica* and obtain the limit?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Identifying the sum as ($N$ times) a Riemann sum should inspire us to look at the integral of the function $x^N$ for $0\le x \lt 1$, whose value is $1/(N+1)$, of which here are a few examples for $N=1,4,16,64$:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[x^n, {n, {1, 4, 16, 64}}], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis,  PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Plots of x^n for n=1,4,16,64]

Noticing that this area becomes more and more concentrated near $x \approx 1$, we should then suspect that virtually all of the sum's value is coming from the last few terms.  Why not, then, use *Mathematica* to explore this?

```
Table[Limit[Sum[((k - 1)/n)^n, {k, n - i, n}], n -> \[Infinity]], {i, 0, 4}]
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{e},\frac{1+e}{e^2},\frac{1+e+e^2}{e^3},\frac{1+e+e^2+e^3}{e^4},\frac{1+e+e^2+e^3+e^4}{e^5}\right\}$

The pattern is clear. *Mathematica* will identify it:

```
FindSequenceFunction[%][i]
```

> $\frac{e^{-i} \left(e^i-1\right)}{e-1}$

That is, we can *speculate* from this evidence that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \sum_{k=n-i}^n\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^n = \frac{e^{-i} \left(e^i-1\right)}{e-1}.$$

It looks good when we compare the sums to the limiting value of the right hand side, easily seen (or computed by *Mathematica*) to be $1/(e-1)\approx 0.581977$:

```
DiscretePlot[1/(E-1) - Sum[((k-1)/n)^n, {k, 1, n}], {n, 10, 1000, 20}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]]
```

[image: Discrete plot of residuals]

*If we can mathematically justify taking the double limit*--first with respect to $n$, then with respect to $i$--then we can conclude the right hand side converges to $1/(e-1)$.  I leave that reasoning to the interested reader.